# Kenyan citizen travelling to Sweden

Tags: visas, schengen, sweden, kenyan-citizens

I am preparing to travel to Sweden for missionary work with our church. I am the single mom of a one-year-old child and I'm self-employed. My business is fairly new, having started in September of last year. I also have a partner.

Can I get a bank statement as soon as some money is deposited? We are planning to apply before March 15th. Also, does attaching my son's birth certificate show very strong ties to my home country? Lastly, can I include my uncle as a sponsor? Accommodation is provided by the church; we are only paying for flight tickets.

Comment: Is your son going with you, or he remains in Kenya?

Comment: How much time are you planning to spend away from home? A person with new business might not have much spare time! Also, have other people in your church been to Europe and returned? If not, you may be being trafficked or led into an immigration scam.

Answer (score 1):

They want to see banks statements to see a stable pattern of income and expenditure. Having a bank account isn't saying much, having money on it isn't saying much either. Are you keeping your business and personal accounts separate?

For a tourist or business visitor visa, you should carefully check if your missionary work is allowed. You do not have to get cash payments to make this work. Ask on Expatriates.SE for work visas.

A sponsor is not the same as a character witness. Is your uncle involved in paying for your trip, or arranging it? Then it needs to be mentioned. Otherwise you should only mention him if his presence is the reason why you go to Sweden, but you are traveling for work, right?